# Need help in Indexing on xmltype column in oracle for specific xpath

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, xmltype

I am using structured storage type for xmltype column (i.e. XML Schema is defined).
And I am willing to perform huge number of where clauses on the values of specific xpath in the xml.

Which xmltype indexing i should go for?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of subtleties when it comes to indexing XML, and it's not possible for us to give you a definitive answer on such scant information.  You will have to experiment a bit.

However, if you have XPATH expressions which you know will constitute the bulk of your querying then you should start by ceatingr an XDB.XMLTYPE index specifying those paths in the parameters clause.  Something like this example from the documentation:

```
CREATE INDEX po_xmlindex_ix ON po_clob (OBJECT_VALUE) INDEXTYPE IS XDB.XMLINDEX
  PARAMETERS ('PATHS (INCLUDE (/PurchaseOrder/LineItems//* 
                               /PurchaseOrder/Reference))');
```

But you really need to read the documentation.  [Find it here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_indexing.htm#CHDCJIJB).

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I am looking into it. I was expecting the help from someone who already tried it.

Comment: I have worked with XML Indexes before.  That's why I am telling you an exact solution will depend very much on your *precise situation*.  A vague question can only expect a vague answer.